# Checked out an old branch and work is gone

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout, data-loss

This is exactly what I did:

I did a lot of work on branch `new-feature`.

I added and committed it

```
git add .
git commit -m "did lots of work"
```

I checked out `main`

```
git checkout main
```

I merged `new-feature` into `main`

```
git merge --no-ff new-feature
```

I checked out a new branch.

```
git checkout -b new-branch
```

did lots of work there, added, committed it, checkout out `main` and merged it in, just as before.

Then I checked out `new-feature` and all my work I committed back then is gone!!

I don't know what happened. It was definitely all there when I committed it originally. Where did it go? It's almost like the last commit I made - the most important one - on that branch, it gone!

Any advice?? (freaking out a bit here)

Comment: git does not forget commits. Either there never were commits, or they have been removed, accidentally maybe, or you are simply working on another clone of the repository now which has not get received the commits in question. I often miss that some command like a commit fails. Happens. Then there simply is no commit.

Comment: I definitely made the commits. I noticed now, that my command prompt was in a subfolder of my main projects when I made the commits.. could that be the issue?

Comment: Is there any way I can get my work back :-( ?

Comment: Making a commit in a subfolder is perfectly fine.

Comment: If you can "get back your work" is something I really cannot answer, sorry. I know nothing about your repository, what you did (or think you did), what really happened. I cannot say anything about all that. Sorry.

Comment: One idea: Could it be that you actually did _not_ checkout that old branch "new-feature", but a new one? Remember: those are just names, maybe the old or the new one is spelled slightly different? List your branches and check.

Comment: @arkascha I wish. But it's definitely that branch. I have Atlassian SourceTree open to verify

Comment: @arkascha I'm totally screwed :-(  :-( :-(

Comment: Ah, so you have a remote clone of the repository? But you did not push the commits there? Why not? But anyways: as said: _git does not simply forget commits_. Either there never were commits or they were removed or you are looking at the wrong place. Sorry that I can't be of more help.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to look through the bash history step by step to see what has _really_ been done. That sometimes delivers big surprises...

Comment: @arkascha I did. I have my command prompt window open and I can see everything I did for the past few days. It's weird.. it seems when I made the commits to my work, those files didn't show up with an `M` next to them. They don't appear.

Comment: Aha. So you did not actually create a commit with these changes (whyever). That explains why there is no commit now. SO the question is: 1. where were the modifications and 2. are they still there somewhere? Maybe you stashed? Maybe those were new files you did not add? And: you say you did the commit in a subdirectory. That is fine, _but_: it won't consider files outside that subfolder. But that would _not_ explain why the changes are gone. They would just not get submitted and either be left or prevent a switch of branches because of a collision which git would tell you.

Comment: @arkascha then that is the issue. I made the commits while in `A/B/C` but the files I changed were in `A/P/Z`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73535/discussion-between-arkascha-and-imray).

Comment: if you did the `git commit -m "did lots of work"` correctly and it wasn't too long time ago, you should be able to find it by `git reflog`, search for the "did lots of work"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my mistake was that I was navigated to a subfolder of my base folder when I made the commits and the changes I wanted to commit were in a different subfolder.